# Replace nulls in table B with values in table A using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a table like this:

```
price_families (Table A):
ID     UPC      
1      123
1      456
2      789
2      111
1      121
```

And a second table:

```
sales_volume (Table B): 
UPC    sales    volume  
123    13.99      2.99
456    null       null 
121    14.99      1.99
789    31.88     22.99
111    null       null 
121    null       null
```

What I want is to replace the null values in Table B with the sales/volume values of a different UPC of the same product family (using Table A to determine price families, joining on UPC) and to order by sales desc, volume desc (for each price family).

What is the optimal way to do this? Can I use coalesce() here, or perhaps a case statement?

My output should be this:

```
output (Table C): 
UPC    sales    volume  
123    13.99      2.99
456    13.99      2.99 
121    14.99      1.99
789    31.88     22.99
111    31.88     22.99 
121    13.99      2.99
```

Comment: "Replace nulls in table A ..." There are no nulls in your table A. Please make your question consistent. Also, the "optimal way" depends on your definition of "optimal". Shortest, fastest, safest, simplest, ...? The "fastest" way, for example, depends on undisclosed details. Postgres version, table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement), cardinalities, frequency of NULL values. How many rows per UPC, ... [Consider instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info)

Comment: For ideas on how to do it "optimally" have a look at the [The Last non NULL Puzzle](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle) article by Itzik Ben-Gan. It is written for SQL Server, but Postgres supports all the SQL features that are used in that article.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . One method uses tuples for the assignment:

```
update b
    set (sales, volume) = (select b2.sales, b2.volume
                           from b b2 join
                                a
                                on b2.upc = a.upc
                           where b2.sales is not null and b2.volume is not null
                           order by b2.sales desc, b2.volume desc
                           limit 1
                          )
    where sales is null and volume is null;
```

EDIT:

If you just want the `select` query:

```
select b.upc,
       coalesce(b.sales, b2.sales) as sales,
       coalesce(b.volume, b2.volume) as volume
from b left join lateral
     (select b2.sales, b2.volume
      from b b2 join
           a
           on b2.upc = a.upc
      where b2.sales is not null and b2.volume is not null
      order by b2.sales desc, b2.volume desc
      limit 1
     ) b2
     on 1=1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used the select query and I'm getting error: SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated. Any idea why?

Comment: @Hana . . . I always seem to leave the `on` clause out of left lateral joins.